# service tomcat9 isn't working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, virtual-machine, tomcat9

when I type the following code:

```
service tomcat9 start
```

I get in response:

```
tomcat9: unrecognized service
```

I am trying to install JDK in Ubuntu 18.04 on virtual machine.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to start Tomcat in an environment without System D ready (System D is required to use `service`)

If you are using docker, these are the commands to start and Ubuntu 18.04 with System D ready for Tomcat 9:

`docker run -d --name tomcat9 --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-ubuntu:18.04`

`docker exec -it tomcat9 /bin/bash -c "apt-get update; apt-get install -y tomcat9; service tomcat9 start; bash"`

(let's please thank jrei for such cool docker solution here: https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-ubuntu/dockerfile)